# Configuring TCP services with nginx ingress on minikube/k8s

Tags: networking, nginx, tcp, kubernetes, minikube

I'm new to k8s/minikube (and to some extent, unix networking in general) so if I ask something that seems to make no sense, I'll be happy to clarify!

## Goal

I want to configure a port-based TCP ingress, as described briefly in the [nginx-ingress docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/). In particular, I want to use the `webpack-dev-server` from inside `minikube`.

## Error

When it's set up according to my best understanding, I still get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when requesting `local.web:3001/client.js`. That is, navigating in my browser to 'local.web/' brings up the page, but without the bundle that `webpack` is meant to be producing. The request for that fails.

## Configuration

Moving from host machine to minikube pod, I have

#### /etc/hosts:

On my dev machine, I set `local.web` to the minikube IP

`$ echo "$(minikube ip) local.web" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts`

#### Ingress:

```
{
  "kind": "Ingress",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "dev-web-ingress",
    "namespace": "dev",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/dev/ingresses/dev-web-ingress",
    "uid": "64ebfc93-612e-11e9-8df7-0800270e7244",
    "resourceVersion": "280750",
    "generation": 3,
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-04-17T16:32:30Z",
    "labels": {
      "platform": "advocate",
      "tier": "frontend"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"extensions/v1beta1\",\"kind\":\"Ingress\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"kubernetes.io/ingress.class\":\"nginx\"},\"labels\":{\"platform\":\"advocate\",\"tier\":\"frontend\"},\"name\":\"dev-web-ingress\",\"namespace\":\"dev\"},\"spec\":{\"rules\":[{\"host\":\"local.web\",\"http\":{\"paths\":[{\"backend\":{\"serviceName\":\"dev-adv-web-service\",\"servicePort\":\"http\"},\"path\":\"/\"}]}}]}}\n",
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "host": "local.web",
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "path": "/",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "dev-adv-web-service",
                "servicePort": "http"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {
      "ingress": [
        {
          "ip": "10.0.2.15"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### TCP Services

```
{
  "kind": "ConfigMap",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "tcp-services",
    "namespace": "dev",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/dev/configmaps/tcp-services",
    "uid": "5e456f3e-622e-11e9-bcf8-0800270e7244",
    "resourceVersion": "295220",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-04-18T23:04:50Z",
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"data\":{\"3001\":\"dev/dev-adv-web-service:3001\",\"9290\":\"dev/dev-echoserver:8080\"},\"kind\":\"ConfigMap\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"tcp-services\",\"namespace\":\"dev\"}}\n"
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "3001": "dev/dev-adv-web-service:3001",
  }
}
```

#### Service:

```
{
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "dev-adv-web-service",
    "namespace": "dev",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/dev/services/dev-adv-web-service",
    "uid": "64e3c65d-612e-11e9-8df7-0800270e7244",
    "resourceVersion": "280675",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-04-17T16:32:30Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "adv-web",
      "tier": "frontend"
    },
    "annotations": [... edited for clarity]
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "http",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 3000,
        "nodePort": 31246
      },
      {
        "name": "http2",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 3001,
        "targetPort": 3001,
        "nodePort": 31392
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "app": "frontend-container",
      "tier": "frontend"
    },
    "clusterIP": "10.108.24.80",
    "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "sessionAffinity": "None",
    "externalTrafficPolicy": "Cluster"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }
}
```

#### Pod

```
{
  "kind": "Pod",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "dev-adv-web-768767454f-wxvnh",
    "generateName": "dev-adv-web-768767454f-",
    "namespace": "dev",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/dev/pods/dev-adv-web-768767454f-wxvnh",
    "uid": "65de844e-622c-11e9-bcf8-0800270e7244",
    "resourceVersion": "294073",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-04-18T22:50:43Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "frontend-container",
      "pod-template-hash": "768767454f",
      "tier": "frontend"
    },
    "ownerReferences": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
        "kind": "ReplicaSet",
        "name": "dev-adv-web-768767454f",
        "uid": "4babd3e7-613d-11e9-8df7-0800270e7244",
        "controller": true,
        "blockOwnerDeletion": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "frontend-repo",
        "hostPath": {
          "path": "/Users/me/Projects/code/frontend",
          "type": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "default-token-7rfht",
        "secret": {
          "secretName": "default-token-7rfht",
          "defaultMode": 420
        }
      }
    ],
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "adv-web-container",
        "image": "localhost:5000/react:dev",
        "command": [
          "npm",
          "run",
          "dev"
        ],
        "ports": [
          {
            "name": "http",
            "containerPort": 3000,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "name": "http2",
            "containerPort": 3001,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "env": [
          {
            "name": "HOSTNAME_PUBLISHED",
            "valueFrom": {
              "configMapKeyRef": {
                "name": "dev-frontend-configmap",
                "key": "HOSTNAME_PUBLISHED"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "LOCAL_DOMAIN",
            "valueFrom": {
              "configMapKeyRef": {
                "name": "dev-frontend-configmap",
                "key": "LOCAL_DOMAIN"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "HOST",
            "valueFrom": {
              "configMapKeyRef": {
                "name": "dev-frontend-configmap",
                "key": "HOST"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "WEBPACK_PUBLISHED_PORT",
            "valueFrom": {
              "configMapKeyRef": {
                "name": "dev-frontend-configmap",
                "key": "WEBPACK_PUBLISHED_PORT"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "WEBPACK_LISTEN_PORT",
            "valueFrom": {
              "configMapKeyRef": {
                "name": "dev-frontend-configmap",
                "key": "WEBPACK_LISTEN_PORT"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "API_URL",
            "valueFrom": {
              "configMapKeyRef": {
                "name": "dev-frontend-configmap",
                "key": "API_URL"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL",
            "valueFrom": {
              "configMapKeyRef": {
                "name": "dev-frontend-configmap",
                "key": "LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL",
            "valueFrom": {
              "configMapKeyRef": {
                "name": "dev-frontend-configmap",
                "key": "NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "resources": {},
        "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "frontend-repo",
            "mountPath": "/code"
          },
          {
            "name": "default-token-7rfht",
            "readOnly": true,
            "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
          }
        ],
        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
        "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
        "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
      }
    ],
    "restartPolicy": "Always",
    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
    "serviceAccountName": "default",
    "serviceAccount": "default",
    "nodeName": "minikube",
    "securityContext": {},
    "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
    "tolerations": [
      {
        "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
        "operator": "Exists",
        "effect": "NoExecute",
        "tolerationSeconds": 300
      },
      {
        "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
        "operator": "Exists",
        "effect": "NoExecute",
        "tolerationSeconds": 300
      }
    ],
    "priority": 0,
    "enableServiceLinks": true
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Running",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Initialized",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-04-18T22:50:43Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "Ready",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-04-18T22:50:45Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "ContainersReady",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-04-18T22:50:45Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "PodScheduled",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-04-18T22:50:43Z"
      }
    ],
    "hostIP": "10.0.2.15",
    "podIP": "172.17.0.13",
    "startTime": "2019-04-18T22:50:43Z",
    "containerStatuses": [
      {
        "name": "adv-web-container",
        "state": {
          "running": {
            "startedAt": "2019-04-18T22:50:44Z"
          }
        },
        "lastState": {},
        "ready": true,
        "restartCount": 0,
        "image": "localhost:5000/react:dev",
        "imageID": "docker-pullable://localhost:5000/react@sha256:2bfe61ed134044bff4b23f5c057af2f9c480c3c1a1927a485f09f3410528903d",
        "containerID": "docker://57b9b6dafaf2aba8a21d5dd7db3543f4742c00331b49b48dc1561e3b5bd05315"
      }
    ],
    "qosClass": "BestEffort"
  }
}
```

## Hypotheses

One thought was that the namespace on the TCP services `ConfigMap` was wrong. It's not clear to me from the docs where that's supposed to live. I have tried it in the namespace `dev`, where the ingress, service, and deployment/pods live. I also tried adding the `data` entry as above to the `tcp-services` `ConfigMap` in `kube-system`.

The logs for the webpack pod show no errors, so I don't *believe* the problem is at the application level.

Since the `GET local.web/` is returning data from the pod, I am convinced the service is at least partially correct.

I'm willing to perform any debugging you can suggest, and have no illusions that I know anything about what's going on--I'll be grateful for any help offered.

Comment: `In particular, I want to use the webpack-dev-server from inside minikube`. Could you explain why you would like to achieve this?

Comment: I'm trying to set up local development with as much similarity to the production environment as is feasible. I'm also trying to understand the relationships among all the components of the system I'm building.